# CSS rule using JavaScript ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ternary-operator

How to shuffle css rule of div id using javascript ternary operator where condition is set into jquery variable "my_color"

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#my_div")
     .removeClass("horizontal vertical")
     .addClass( ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gray'].indexOf(my_color) != -1 ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical');
});
</script>
```

As stated above my class shuffles horizontal to vertical for particular color value of `"my_color"` as condition. for same condition I want to shuffle float of list item from `left` with `horizontal` to `none` with `vertical`.my css style-sheet contain list item "#my_div li".

css:

```
#my_div li{float:left}
```

And how can I shuffle multiple css for using same ternary conditional operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is *something like this* what you mean ?

```
<style>
.float_left { float:left; }
.float_none { float:none; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#my_div")
     .removeClass("horizontal vertical float_left")
     .addClass( ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gray'].indexOf(my_color) != -1 ? 'horizontal float_left' : 'vertical float_none');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are welcome. So, you accept my answer then? If so, please click the green tick if it's not too much trouble!

Comment: yeah definitely chris ! just waiting for more suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use CSS for this:

```
.horizontal li {
    float: left;
}
.vertical li {
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: I can add it like urs, but I want to add more css rule for same case.